# .Net Core MVC - cannot get 406 - Not Acceptable, always returns 200 OK with Json

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, http-status-code-406

I want my application to respect browser accept header and return 406, if it does not match the response format.

I have this options set in Mvc configuration:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The collection of the services.</param>
    /// <returns>The provider of the service.</returns>
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // add mvc services
        services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

                    options.CacheProfiles.Add(
                        "CodebookCacheProfile",
                        new CacheProfile()
                        {
                            Duration = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds
                        });
                })
                .AddControllersAsServices()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEmptyToNullConverter());
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(true));
                });

        // add response compression services
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.EnableForHttps = true;
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        // add application services
        services.AddSwaggerDoc()
                .AddConfiguration(configuration)
                .AddModel()
                .AddDataAccess(configuration)
                .AddAuthentication(configuration)
                .AddDomainServices()
                .AddSchedulerContainer(() => serviceProvider);

        // initialize container
        serviceProvider = services.CreateServiceProvider();

        return serviceProvider;
    }
```

When I try to send request like this: (with Accept header set on whatever, for example "text/xml")

I always get 200 OK - with "application/json"
[image: Request with specified accept header and the response in json format]

My *CountriesController* looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// REST API controller for actions with countries.
/// </summary>    
[AllowAnonymous]
[Area(Area.Common)]
[Route("[area]/Codebooks/[controller]")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "CodebookCacheProfile")]
public class CountriesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICountryService countryService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CountriesController" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="countryService">The country service.</param>
    public CountriesController(ICountryService countryService)
    {
        this.countryService = countryService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryService));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets countries by search settings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="200">The countries was returned correctly.</response>
    /// <response code="401">The unauthorized access.</response>
    /// <response code="406">The not acceptable format.</response>
    /// <response code="500">The unexpected error.</response>
    /// <param name="countrySearchSettings">The search settings of the country.</param>
    /// <returns>Data page of countries.</returns>        
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IDataPage<Country>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiErrorSummary), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [SwaggerOperation("SearchCountries")]
    public IDataPage<Country> Get([FromQuery(Name = "")] CountrySearchSettings countrySearchSettings)
    {
        return countryService.Search(countrySearchSettings);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a country.
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="200">The country was returned correctly.</response>
    /// <response code="400">The country code is not valid.</response>
    /// <response code="401">The unauthorized access.</response>
    /// <response code="406">The not acceptable format.</response>
    /// <response code="500">The unexpected error.</response>
    /// <param name="countryCode">The code of the country.</param>
    /// <returns>Action result.</returns>   
    [HttpGet("{countryCode}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Country), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiValidationErrorSummary), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiErrorSummary), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetCountry")]
    public IActionResult Get(string countryCode)
    {
        var country = countryService.GetByCode(countryCode);
        return Ok(country);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why the request Accept header is always ignored and the response is always 200 OK with correct Json data?
What am I missing? I thought that the setting of *RespectBrowserAcceptHeader*  and *ReturnHttpNotAcceptable* would do the thing... but apparently not.
Why it always falls back to the default Json formatter?

Comment: what does `ICountryService.Search` return?

Comment: `IDataPage<Country>` which is basically custom collection... something like paged list - it contains `IEnumerable<Country>` and other properties like Count, TotalPages, PageNumber, PageSize, etc

Comment: Where is your code that actually generates the 406 result? When you always return the collection, you will always get a 200.

Comment: So I have to manually check what is inside accept header and return 406? Or how to generate 406? I thought it would be automatically returned when the response format differs from what is inside accept header

Comment: My assumptions are based on what is stated in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1) under _Content Negotiation Process_

Answer (score 2):

For `ReturnHttpNotAcceptable` to work, the type returned by an action must be either an `ObjectResult` (e.g. `Ok(retval)`) or a type that does not implement `IActionResult` (in which case the MVC framework will wrap it in an `ObjectResult` for you).

This is because the MVC framework only checks against the value of `ReturnHttpNotAcceptable` in `ObjectResultExecutor`, and not in any of the other `IActionResultExecutor` implementations (like `ViewResultExecutor`). (See source code for [ObjectResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8d66f104f7f2ca42ee8b21f75b0e2b3e1abe2e00/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs) and [ViewResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2414db256f32a047770326d14d8b0e2afd49ba49/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewResultExecutor.cs))

Put simply, make sure that the type you are returning doesn't implement (or inherit from anything that implements) IActionResult.

Comment: Even i had the same problem, Where the return type was IActionResult but the action was returning  an instance of JsonResult always. After i changed to return an instance of objectresult. It worked.!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters().AddApiExplorer();
```

Comment: What does this do, and why will it help the OP?